# Problem with too broad subjects!

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question. look it:

[What is the usage of State Machine in electronic world? [on hold]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106548/what-is-the-usage-of-state-machine-in-electronic-world)

but unfortunately, some have voted to put on hold it along with down-voting it. Why? It's not fair. let's, assume, we are a visitor for this question. when the visitor look it, What do he/she want think about it? I'm sure that I could get a convincing answer. For instance, let's look at the question of number 3, is it really a hard act to provide a example for state machine in C language?
in your opinion, How can I remove the put on hold situation for my question?

Answer (score 6):

That question was correctly closed.

There are a number of problems with this question:

You asked a bunch of questions.  They were nicely enumerated, but there are still too many of them.  That makes it a hassle to answer.

Your individual questions were so broad that it would take a book to answer each of them properly.  This site is simply not equipped for this kind of discussion or long answers.  We are looking for *specific* questions that can be answered in a few paragraphs.  Your overall question was basically *"Teach me about state machines"*.

Particularly see question 1: *"Why they created it and what problems it solved?"*.  This leads me to believe the basic problem is that you don't really know what a state machine is.  Also *"Why did they create it and what problems does it solve?"* would be nicer to read.

Broad question are also difficult to answer because often it's hard to know the right level of information to supply.  For example, it's not clear that you'd understand any answer without a basic introduction to state machines first.

Demanding examples in particular languages is a bit rude.  You have forgotten that you are asking a bunch of volunteers to give you their answers for free.  These people all have other things they could be doing, so have no need to put up with a demanding ingrate.

The language could use a little polishing.  By itself, the English problems would be overlooked. They are relatively mild and it's still clear enough what you seem to mean.  However, this minor annoyance becomes more important when there are other annoyances.  Like it or not, presentation quality is **always** a issue.  Remember the part about people here being volunteers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for down-vote these buth questions(also I have up-voted your answer because seems it's a good answer). Dear Olin, I know you and I think you know me, too. I'm from iran. we have already spoke about myself. I can't speak like a decent american because I'm not completely familiar with your culture. I have a request. please don't think I'm an uncivil.

Comment: @Roh, downvotes on meta don't mean it was wrong to post your question, they just mean somebody disagrees with your proposal.

Comment: @ThePhoton Not just this question. he down-voted the question that I have mentioned in above.